# Value or Text inside TextInput component not visible(in iOS) when I add Modal component

Tags: expo, react-native-ios

[herein image the placeholder or input is not visible in TextInput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejqvz.jpg) I have tried everything including adjsuting the height of TextInput component but the input is not visible when i run expo in ios

this is my InputComponent
    return (

```
 <Modal  visible={props.visible} >
    <View style={styles.inputView}>
        <TextInput placeholder="Course Goal" style={styles.input}
            onChangeText={(enteredGoal)=>(setGoalHandler(enteredGoal))} 
            value={enteredGoal}/>
        <View style={styles.inputButtons}>
            <View style={styles.button}><Button  title="Cancel" 
                color="red" onPress={props.changeModal}/></View>
            <View style={styles.button}><Button title="Add" onPress={()=> 
                 {props.onAddGoal(enteredGoal),
                setEnteredGoal('')}}/></View>
            </View>
       </View>
  </Modal>

)
```

}

Comment: Can you provide more information regarding the components? At the moment it's not possible to exactly pinpoint the problem.

Comment: I have added more details

Answer (score 1):

apparently it's a bug, you can get around it by setting a color for the input